# Could not find endpoint element in .Config File

Tags: wcf, configuration, com+, wcf-endpoint, dllhost

Good day to all,

We've encountered some configuration problem while retrieving an end point from configuration file at creating a ChannelFactory object.

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'no matter service'
>   and contract 'no matter contract' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was found for your application, or
>   because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the
>   client element.

The usual solution at this kind of exception is to add .config file to exe that runs this code.
In this case we're running this code at com+ so i'd created dllhost.exe.config file with all the endpoints.

The intresting thing is that i'm using this service also from a client application and there my wcf platform founds the same endpoint without any problem.
Other endpoints at dllhost.exe.config working fine i think.

By the way the problematic proxy that uses this service is customised Enterprise Library code. 
While debugging the code it is defenetly runs under the dllhost process.

Is there some way to find out it what config file it looks for the endpoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a few days of checking and testing we'd found out 2 ways to solve the problem:

- dllhost.exe.config - should not be edited/created/updated manually,but from MSI.Probably the reason is that is is placed at system32 directory and windows blocks it.
- Better way - is to create for COM+ Service [Application Root Directory](http://staff.newtelligence.net/clemensv/content/binary/image0011234.jpg) and place there 2 files

  - ServiceName.config - Contains list of endpoints
  - ServiceName.manifest - Contains 3 rows

    - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
      <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
      </assembly>`